# PHP echo implode with single along with coma

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to add a single coat along with the coma in my below code and display the data as mentioned below (Expected  output)but iam unable to add  single coat along with coma.

```
   $query ="SELECT * FROM abc WHERE  xyz='xyz' And Standard='xyz' ";
        $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
        $ID = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            $ID[] = $row['ID'];


    }
    $IDall = implode(',', $ID);


    echo $IDall;
```

Current output

```
13,13K,043
```

Expected output

```
'13','13K','043'
```

Comment: Something like `$IDall = '\''.implode('\',\'', $ID).'\'';` should give you what your looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$IDall = "'" . implode("','", $ID) . "'";
```

Comment: Thnx  was expecting the same

Answer (score 0):

All array elements are concatenated only using a single comma in between. You don't add the single quotes, so of course there are no in the output.
In order to add these quotes, you can for example use:

```
$IDall = "'".implode("','", $ID)."'";
```

Explanation: first, you add a single quote before and after every comma, so between each element there are now three characters (','). Also you have to add the missing single quotes in the beginning and end of the resulting string, hence the "'" before and after the implode.